# UITextfield fatal error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image: My Error Screenshot]

In my swift app I am using parse. While getting login register field details into parse, I am getting error like **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** in textfield. Kindly help me. My code is below.

```
//CLASS 1
class login: UIViewController{ 
  @IBAction func create_acc_but(sender: UIButton) { 
    createaccount.shared.create_account() 
   }
}
// CLASS 2

public class createaccount {

let login_obj:login = login()
class var shared: createaccount {
    struct Static {
        static let instance: createaccount = createaccount()
    }
    return Static.instance
 }

func create_account() {


    var user = PFUser()

    user.username = login_obj.username_txtfd.text //receiving error in this line.
    user.email =  login_obj.email_txtfd.text
    user.password = login_obj.passwd_txtfd.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        } else {
            let errorString = error.userInfo // error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
            println(errorString)
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all about wrapping and unwrapping of optional value. This error because you are trying to unwrapping an optional value. Make sure that your property must be declared as optional, like this

```
@IBOutlet var txtNumber1:UITextField!
```

You can access value like this

```
var a:Int! = txtNumber1.text.toInt()
```

For more information on **optional** visit this link: http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/

This will definetly helps you

Comment: hi Indrajeet, thanks for your reply. I am getting textfield's value in same class. but I am accessing through another class. On that time its thrown error, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Yes, this error occurs when proper unwrapping is not done. Try this user.username = login_obj.username_txtfd.text!